# yum showing readline installed but readline command not working

Tags: bash, centos, readline, libreadline, rlwrap

yum My system shows readline installed

```
rlwrap-0.41]$ sudo yum install readline
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
.
.
.
Package readline-6.0-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But when I run `readline` command it doesn't work

```
-bash: readline: command not found
```

I thought command binary may not be on path so tried searching for it but no luck..!!

```
sudo find /usr/ -iname readline
```

basically I'm trying to install `http://freecode.com/projects/rlwrap/`
and the configure is failing saying readline library is not found.

Comment: rlwrap exists as a package in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for CentOS 6.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"readline" is not a command.

If you are trying to build software that uses the readline library then you need to install `readline-devel`.

Answer (score 7):

Got it !!
`readline` development package needs to be installed.
After installing it, I got what I wanted...

```
sudo yum install readline-devel
```