# Can't build optional modules readline and _curses when compiling Python3.4 from source on CentOS7

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, readline

When compiling Python 3.4.3 from source on CentOS 7 the README indicates to run

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

On the second step, `make`, I see

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter
readline              zlib
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

But nothing in the source code for setup.py indicates what to do? It seems like I already have the requisite package?

```
$ sudo yum install readline
...
Package readline-6.2-10.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

How do I get the `readline` module for python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `readline-devel` package

```
$ sudo yum install readline-devel
[...]
Installed:
  readline-devel.x86_64 0:6.2-10.el7

Dependency Installed:
  ncurses-devel.x86_64 0:5.9-14.20130511.el7_4

Dependency Updated:
  ncurses.x86_64 0:5.9-14.20130511.el7_4   [...]

Complete!
```

Then re-run `make`

```
$ make
[...]
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _dbm                  _gdbm
_lzma                 _sqlite3              _ssl
_tkinter              zlib
```

Now both `readline` and `_curses` modules are installed, and absent from the list of missing modules.

I got the hint from an answer on this question: [yum showing readline installed but readline command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129623/yum-showing-readline-installed-but-readline-command-not-working)

This pattern proved to work well for the other missing packages. `ssl` required the `openssl-devel` package, and `zlib` required `zlib-devel`.